# the difference between parsing and compiling

Tags: parsing, assembly, compiler-construction, computer-science

I am new to the world of the assembly and would like to know what parsing means in this context and the difference between parsing and compiling. Thank you.

Comment: Assembly language doesn't get compiled, it gets assembled.  Or are you talking about parsing & compiling a higher-level language like C to create text asm code?

Comment: A *parser* is a program that reads human readable code and understands it's grammar, yielding an *abstract syntax tree.*

Comment: Fundamentally, a parser is a recognizer. In its most basic form, it takes an input and tells if that matches the grammar it was constructed to recognize.  If the input doesn't match, that's a syntax error.  The input is a sequence of something, like text or tokens, and in a more useful form, a parser outputs a data structure of the recognized syntactic constructs of the input sequence, so a parser is also a deserializer.  A complier contains a parser and an code generator, which is an emitter that generates machine code or assembly (or other), another sequence, so the emitter is a serializer.

Comment: Compilers also often have much more than just parser and code generator: optimiztions, type checking, among other features.

Comment: An assembler is arguably a very primitive compiler, but so primitive that we generally won't call it a compiler, or call using it, compilation.

Answer (score 3):

A **recognizer** does **verify** that a sequence of symbols **belongs** or not to a given language. With the assumption that it terminates, it will terminate with a Boolean value: true (belongs) or false (does not belong).

A **parser** is a **recognizer** that also outputs the **derivation steps** that one can use to build a **syntax tree**.

**Parsing** is the process that the parser performs.

A **translator** does **translate** from one language to another.

A **compiler** is a **translator** that **translates** from a high-level language to a low-level language.

**Compiling** is the process that the compiler performs.

A **decompiler** is a **translator** that **translates** from a **low-level** language to a **high-level** language.

An **assembly language** is low-level language that uses mnemonics that are very close to a given **machine language**. It is the "human friendly" version of the machine language, often with some extras like comments.

A **machine language** is the language that is used to write **machine code** and that will be executed by the hardware. For example, the Central Processor Unit (CPU).

It seems to me that its more correct to say that the assembly language is **compiled** by an **assembler** to produce a machine code written in a machine language. The term **assembled** is also used in this case. I write **compiled**, because, the assembly languages express not exactly the machine language, but have extras, that I think is somehow "higher" level compared to the machine language.

Comment: One key difference between an assembler and a compiler is that every line of asm maps to some machine code *independently* of the surrounding lines, more or less.  e.g. for x86 `xor eax, eax` emits 2 bytes (31 C0) into the output at the current position, in whatever section you're currently in.  You just assemble bytes into the output file, and it's up to the programmer for there to be any meaning to those bytes.  Some assemblers like MASM with "high level" features blur this by letting you declare things like symbolic names for local variables.  But there are similarities to compilation, yes.

Comment: "more or less" is not good enough to formally define a translation. Clearly from an assembly language to a machine language at least the comments are lost (not to talk about macros, names, labels and so on). Even that they are not a functional part of the final machine code they are still part of the assembly language. I do not think that there is a formal definition of what exactly an assembly language must be. For these reasons I think that a compilation is the proper term.

Comment: I didn't say the mapping was reversible.   When I said "more or less", I was mostly talking about things like whether a symbol is defined as a label or an `equ` constant in assemblers where that's different (e.g. MASM syntax).  I don't see what losing coming has to do with anything.  As for macros, we normally look at them as a preprocessing step before actual assembly, same as with C `#if` and `#define` being a separate C preprocessor step that happens before actual compilation.

Comment: Anyway yes, with a broad definition of "compiling", "assembling" is a subset of it. 
 I haven't seen a formal definition of it, but I think the key defining factor is that it comes down to assembling bytes (or bits or whatever) into an output file or section, and without needing to keep any amount of context besides a symbol table.  e.g. you could have an assembly language for something other than machine code (like an h.264 bitstream), just like you can compile documents to XML or whatever.